# What is the proper way to check if a user has liked a thread when he GET the thread?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model

I am implementing a `like` feature, the user can like and unlike a thread.

```
The thread model is like this:

const ThreadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        id: { type: ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' },
        screen_name: { type: String, required: true },
        picture: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    theme: { type: String },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: {
        count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    },
    likes: {
        count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        users: [{
            _id: false,
            id: { type: ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' },
            screen_name: { type: String, required: true },
            picture: { type: String, required: true },
        }],
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

Something tricky is that when the user sends the request to get the thread information, I need to tell the client whether this user has liked this thread before or not.

Does that mean that every time when the client sends a request to get the thread, I need to loop through `thread.likes.users` to find whether his ID is there? This check seems pretty heavy especially when the user tries to retrieve a list...

Any better solution for this?

The requirement is simple, just before the user even clicks the `like` button, the state should already there to indicate if this thread has been liked by this user or not.

Comment: Expanding/Summarizing on the [detail in the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006521/how-to-model-a-likes-voting-system-with-mongodb), from a "client" perspective you only really "need" know if the "current user" has already liked the "thread". So you simply project the matched item from the array with a GET. `Thread.findOne({ "_id": threadId }, { "likes.users": { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": userId } })` and the rest of the projection. But that is actually expanded on in that answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn Still thanks, read that answer, helperful, but the elemMatch in mongoose is a little bit confuse, you save my day!

Comment: Sorry my bad. The `$elemMatch` side would rather be like `{ "likes.users": { "$elemMatch": { "id": ObjectId('593a9ea21736ec9b1a9e909b') } } }`. The example in the answer was using `$eq` because the array was only comprised of `ObjecId` values, as opposed to your structure which has sub-documents with an `id` property. There is a link to the documentation in the question as well.

Comment: I'm rolling back your edits. Please [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead since you are changing the question from what you originally asked.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry, no problem now, I use `.elemMatch( 'likes.users', { 'id': '593a9ea21736ec9b1a9e909d' })` , works now.

Comment: Here, you [**Ask a new Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This is not a threaded discussion. One question, One answer ( or a couple of answers sometimes ). You asked one question here and were told it already has an answer. Your "trying to adapt that answer to your code" is a **New Question**. Please click on the link and do so.