# Is there a way to figure out why the update result is 0 in mongoose or mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a thread model in mongoose, which has an `id` field of course and an `likes` field which includes all the users who has liked this thread before so that people can't like the same thread twice.

```
const ThreadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        id: { type: ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' },
        screen_name: { type: String, required: true },
        picture: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    theme: { type: String },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: {
        count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    },
    likes: {
        count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        users: [{
            _id: false,
            id: { type: ObjectID, ref: 'User' },
            screen_name: { type: String },
            picture: { type: String },
        }],
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

When I do an update, I will validate the `threadID` and `likes.users.id`, and only do the update when the 2 conditions match.

```
addLike(threadID, user) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.updateOne(
                {
                    _id: threadID,
                    'likes.users.id': { $ne: user.id },
                },
                {
                    $push: { 'likes.users': user },
                    $inc: { 'likes.count': 1 },
                },
                { safe: true }
            ).exec()
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result.nModified) {
                        resolve(result);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error('Already liked or no such thread.'));
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
};
```

It works. And the `result` I get is something like this:

> `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`

I can use `nModified` to know whether the update happens or not. 
When `nModified = 0` it means nothing changes. Which means either is no thread match `threadID` or the user.id has already in `likes.users.id`.

My problem is:

I want to generate a more clear error message rather than 'Already liked or no such thread.' I want to know the which case it is, is it `already liked`? or is it `no such thread`.

I know i can achieve this by `findById` first, check than update.
But is there a better solution? Thanks

Comment: It's not an error. This is intentional and actually indicates the supplied `user.id` is in fact already present in the `likes.users.id`. This is clear because of `n: 0` which means nothing was matched. And that is the intention since you do not want to increment the like count nor put the voting using in the array when they are already there.

Comment: I'm fairly positive I already pointed you to ["How to Model a “likes” voting system with MongoDB?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28006849/2313887) which already does have a pretty detailed account of why this is the case and is intentional. Perhaps you should show a present document you have to modify with this, the data you are sending and what you expect to happen. So you are either passing something wrong, or it's doing exactly what it should.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, learned a lot through that post, thanks. And it totally works. I just want to make the error message more clear. I mean, customize error at application level. :)

Comment: Then include some more detail in your question like you were asked to! If you don't understand "why?", then include a sample document and the update parameters you are sending. Then I for one am more than happy to further explain what is happening given that case. Presently your question tells us nothing. That's why it does not have an answer. Provide the data if you want help. Please.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry for delay, update the question, should be more clear now :)