# Upsert Using an Array Without Creating Duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having trouble 'upserting' to my array. The code below creates duplicates in my `answers` array which I definitely do not want and by now it's apparent `$push` will not work. I have tried using the different methodologies I see on SO for a while now but none are working for me. With this web app, users are allows to view a question on the website and respond with a 'yes' or 'no' `response` and they are allowed to change(upsert) their `response` at any one time meaning a sort of upsert takes place on the db at different times. How do get around this?

```
var QuestionSchema = Schema ({
    title       :String,
    admin       :{type: String, ref: 'User'},
    answers     :[{type:  Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Answer'}]
});

var AnswerSchema = Schema ({
    _question   :{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'},
    employee    :{type: String, ref: 'User'},
    response    :String,
    isAdmin     :{type: Boolean, ref: 'User'}
})

var UserSchema = Schema({
    username    : String,
    isAdmin     : {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);


           Question.update(
                {_id: req.body.id},
                {$push: {answers: {_question: req.body.id, 
                                    employee: req.body.employee, 
                                    response: req.body.response, //this variable changes (yes/no/null)
                                     isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin}}},
                {safe: true, upsert: true},
                function(err, model) {

                }
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it you seem a little confused and it's reflected in your schema. You don't seem to fully grasp the differences between "embedded" and "referenced" since your schema is actually an invalid "mash" of the two techniques.

Probably best to walk you through both of them.

### Embedded Model

So instead of the schema you have defined, you should in fact have something more like this:

```
var QuestionSchema = Schema ({
    title       :String,
    admin       :{type: String, ref: 'User'},
    answers     :[AnswerSchema]
});

var AnswerSchema = Schema ({
    employee    :{type: String, ref: 'User'},
    response    :String,
    isAdmin     :{type: Boolean, ref: 'User'}
})

mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
```

**NOTE**: `Question` is the **only** actual model here. The `AnswerSchema` is completely "embedded".

Note the clear definition of the "schema" where the `"answers"` property in `Question` is defined as an "array" of `AnswerSchema`. This is how you do embedding and keep control of the types within the object inside the array.

As for the update, there is a clear logic pattern but you are simply not enforcing it. All you need to do is "tell" the update that you *do not want to* "push" a new item if something for that "unique" `"employee"` in the array already exists.

Also. This is **NOT** and "upsert". Upsert implies "creating a new one", which is different to what you want. You want to "push" to the array of an "existing" Question. If you leave "upsert" on there, then something not found creates a new Question. Which is of course wrong here.

```
Question.update(
  { 
    "_id": req.body.id,
    "answers.employee": { "$ne": req.body.employee },
    }
  },
  { "$push": {
    "answers": { 
      "employee": req.body.employee, 
      "response": req.body.response,
      "isAdmin": req.body.isAdmin
    }
  }},
  function(err, numAffected) {

  });
```

That will look to check that the "unique" `"employee"` in the array members already and will only [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) where it is not already there.

As a bonus, if you intend to allow the user to "change their answer" then we do this incantation with [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/):

```
Question.collection.bulkWrite(
  [
    { "updateOne": { 
      "filter": {
        "_id": req.body.id,
        "answers.employee": req.body.employee,
      },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "answers.$.response": req.body.response,
        }
      }
    }},
    { "updateOne": { 
      "filter": {
        "_id": req.body.id,
        "answers.employee": { "$ne": req.body.employee },
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "answers": { 
            "employee": req.body.employee, 
            "response": req.body.response,
            "isAdmin": req.body.isAdmin
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  ],
  function(err, writeResult) {

  }
);
```

This effectively puts two updates in one. The first to attempt to alter an existing answer and [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) the response at the matched position, and the second to attempt to add a new answer where one was not found on the question.

### Referenced Model

With a "referenced" model you actually have the real members of the `Answer` within their own collection. So instead the schema is defined like this:

```
var QuestionSchema = Schema ({
    title       :String,
    admin       :{type: String, ref: 'User'},
    answers     :[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]
});

var AnswerSchema = Schema ({
    _question   :{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'},
    employee    :{type: String, ref: 'User'},
    response    :String,
    isAdmin     :{type: Boolean, ref: 'User'}
})

mongoose.model('Answer', answerSchema);
mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
```

**N.B** The other ref's here to `User` such as :

```
    employee    :{type: String, ref: 'User'},
    isAdmin     :{type: Boolean, ref: 'User'}
```

These are also really incorrect, and also should be of `Schema.Type.ObjectId` as they **will** "reference" the actual `_id` field of `User`. But this is actually outside of the scope of this question as asked, so if you still don't grasp that after this read, then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so someone can explain. On with the rest of the answer.

That's the "general" shape of the schema though, with the important thing being the `"ref"` to the `'Anwser'` "model", which is by the registered name. You can optionally just use your `"_question"` field in modern mongoose versions with a "virtual", but I'm skipping over "Adavanced Usage" for now and keeping it simple with an array of "references" still in the `Question` model.

In this case, since the `Answer` model is actually in it's own "collection", then the operations actually become "upserts". Where we only want to "create" when there is no `"employee"` response to the given `"_question"` id.

Also demonstrating with a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chain instead:

```
Answer.update(
  { "_question": req.body.id, "employee": req.body.employee },
  { 
    "$set": {
      "response": req.body.reponse
    },
    "$setOnInsert": {
      "isAdmin": req.body.isAdmin
    }
  },
  { "upsert": true }
).then(resp => {
  if ( resp.hasOwnProperty("upserted") ) {
    return Question.update(
      { "_id": req.body.id, "answers": { "$ne": resp.upserted[0]._id  },
      { "$push": { "answers": resp.upserted[0]._id  } }
    ).exec()
  }
  return;
}).then(resp => {
   // either undefined where it was not an upsert or 
   // the update result from Question where it was
}).catch(err => { 
   // something
})
```

This is actually a simple statement since *"when matched"* we want to change the `"response"` data with the payload of the request, and really only when *"upserting"* or "creating/inserting" is when we actually change other data such as the `"employee"` ( which is always implied for create as part of the query expression ) and the `"isAdmin"` which clearly should not change with each update request we then explicitly use [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) so it **only** writes those two fields on an actual "create".

In the "Promise Chain" we actually look to see if the update request to `Answer` actually resulted in an "upsert", and when it does we want to append to the array of `Question` where it does not already exist. In much the same way as the "embedded" example, it's best to look to see if the array actually has the item before modifying with the "update". Alternately you could [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) here and just let the query match the `Question` by `_id`. To me though, that's a wasted write.

---

### Summary

Those are your different approaches to how you handle this. Each has their own use cases for which you can see a general summary some other answers of mine in:

- [Mongoose populate vs object nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096822/2313887) which is an overview of the different approaches and reasons behind them
- [How to Model a “likes” voting system with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28006849/2313887) which gives a bit more detail on the *"unique array upserts"* technique for "embedded" models.

Not "required" reading, but it may help expand your insight into which approach is best for your particular case.

---

### Working Example

Copy these and put them in a directory and do an `npm install` to install local dependencies. The code will run and create the collections in the database making the alterations.

Logging is turned on with `mongoose.set(debug,true)` so you should look at the console output and see what it does, along with the resulting collections where answers will be recorded to the related questions, and overwritten instead of "duplicating" where that was also the intent.

Change the connection string if you have to. But that is all you should change in this listing for it's purpose. Both approaches described in the answer are demonstrated.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "colex",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.4.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.29",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.7"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/coltest');

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

const answerSchemaA = new Schema({
  employee: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  response: String,
});

const answerSchemaB = new Schema({
  question: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'QuestionB' },
  employee: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  response: String,
});

const questionSchemaA = new Schema({
  title: String,
  admin: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  answers: [answerSchemaA]
});

const questionSchemaB = new Schema({
  title: String,
  admin: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  answers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'AnswerB' }]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const AnswerB = mongoose.model('AnswerB', answerSchemaB);

const QuestionA = mongoose.model('QuestionA', questionSchemaA);
const QuestionB = mongoose.model('QuestionB', questionSchemaB);


async.series(
  [
    // Clear data
    (callback) => async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
      model.remove({},callback),callback),

    // Create some data
    (callback) =>
      async.each([
        {
          "model": "User",
          "object": {
            "_id": "594a322619ddbd437193c759",
            "name": "Admin",
            "isAdmin": true
          }
        },
        {
          "model": "User",
          "object": {
            "_id":  "594a323919ddbd437193c75a",
            "name": "Bill"
          }
        },
        {
          "model": "User",
          "object": {
            "_id":  "594a327b19ddbd437193c75b",
            "name": "Ted"
          }
        },
        {
          "model": "QuestionA",
          "object": {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "admin": "594a322619ddbd437193c759",
            "title": "Question A Model"
          }
        },
        {
          "model": "QuestionB",
          "object": {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "admin": "594a322619ddbd437193c759",
            "title": "Question B Model"
          }
        }
      ],(data,callback) => mongoose.model(data.model)
        .create(data.object,callback),
      callback
    ),

    // Submit Answers for Users - Question A
    (callback) =>
      async.eachSeries(
        [
          {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "employee": "594a323919ddbd437193c75a",
            "response": "Bills Answer"
          },
          {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "employee": "594a327b19ddbd437193c75b",
            "response": "Teds Answer"
          },
          {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "employee": "594a323919ddbd437193c75a",
            "response": "Bills Changed Answer"
          }
        ].map(d => ([
          { "updateOne": {
            "filter": {
              "_id": ObjectId(d._id),
              "answers.employee": ObjectId(d.employee)
            },
            "update": {
              "$set": { "answers.$.response": d.response }
            }
          }},
          { "updateOne": {
            "filter": {
              "_id": ObjectId(d._id),
              "answers.employee": { "$ne": ObjectId(d.employee) }
            },
            "update": {
              "$push": {
                "answers": {
                  "employee": ObjectId(d.employee),
                  "response": d.response
                }
              }
            }
          }}
        ])),
        (data,callback) => QuestionA.collection.bulkWrite(data,callback),
        callback
      ),

    // Submit Answers for Users - Question A
    (callback) =>
      async.eachSeries(
        [
          {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "employee": "594a323919ddbd437193c75a",
            "response": "Bills Answer"
          },
          {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "employee": "594a327b19ddbd437193c75b",
            "response": "Teds Anwser"
          },
          {
            "_id": "594a32f719ddbd437193c75c",
            "employee": "594a327b19ddbd437193c75b",
            "response": "Ted Changed it"
          }
        ],
        (data,callback) => {
          AnswerB.update(
            { "question": data._id, "employee": data.employee },
            { "$set": { "response": data.response } },
            { "upsert": true }
          ).then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
            if (resp.hasOwnProperty("upserted")) {
              return QuestionB.update(
                { "_id": data._id, "employee": { "$ne": data.employee } },
                { "$push": { "answers": resp.upserted[0]._id } }
              ).exec()
            }
            return;
          }).then(() => callback(null))
          .catch(err => callback(err))
        },
        callback
      )
  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot or this body of information. I understand it better now. I modified my code. My response is not changing though when I attempt. I get a {n: 0, nModified 0, ok 1}. I'm using the `bulkWrite`

Comment: @colin_dev256 It works just fine for me. Neither technique here is anything new and both I have implemented many times over. As I also eluded to, you seem to be struggling with some of the general concepts here. Not entirely sure how I can make it clearer without listing full independent working examples. I would immediately suggest that your "edits" and "data" are not presently in an acceptable state. You should probably try the concepts from scratch here.

Comment: I understood the embedded model well enough according to what I'm trying to achieve(which you totally get). Initially I got a TypeError: Invalid value for schema array path `answers` until I moved the `AnswerSchema` above the `QuestionSchema` (as I googled seemed to be the issue). The error was gone. Could that change have affected the result?

Comment: @colin_dev256 I can't do remote debugging. Either add changed details to your question, or wait patiently whilst I laboriously bang out code for a fully enclosed example. And if you found stuff useful, an upvote would be nice :)

Comment: @colin_dev256 Added a fully working sample for you to run so you cannot misinterpret anything. That at least proves what I am saying is correct. You can then use it as a basis to write your own code following the example.

Comment: @colin_dev256 You've had some time to be able to go through this and see the working example in action with how you deal with creating entries like this. Don't forget that you still have not accepted the answer, and it is answered by the example in the demo.

Comment: yes :)) works!! I think I should update to `async`. Been advised several times. I had project deadline constraints so I had already devised a quick work around with `$pull` and `$push` (as seen with my answer below) before you posted your update. Mine not a very efficient solution though I think. Coz of time I had to debug other sections of the app. Thanks a lot for the help you rendered me during the project. From previous posts/questions too.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my quick work around before Neill updated his answer (I used a `$pull` & `$push`). Works just as his but I'll mark his correct as I believe it's more efficient.

```
                Question.update(
                    {_id: req.body.id},
                    {$pull: {answers: { employee: req.body.employee}}},
                    {safe: true, multi:true, upsert: true},
                    function(err, model) {

                    }
                );

                Question.update(
                    {_id: req.body.id},
                    {$push: {answers: {_question: req.body.id, 
                                        employee: req.body.employee, 
                                        response: req.body.response,
                                         isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin}}},
                    {safe: true, upsert: true},
                    function(err, model) {

                    }
                );
```