# How to toggle an element in array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of string (`ObjectIds`) in mongoDB.
I want to toggle an element in that array: If that element exists in the array, remove it, otherwise push that element.

Example:

```
arr = ["5b608c0769698c3990c64ef3","5b608c0769698c3990c64ef4"]
element = ["5b608c0769698c3990c64ef3"]
```

Final array:

```
arr = ["5b608c0769698c3990c64ef4"]
```

**My use-case:**

I am creating a blog website and in the Blog Schema I am storing the id of each user who has liked that blog, so that I can highlight the like button when blog is shown to the user.

Comment: You cannot... You have to use two queries one for `$pull` and one `$push` for this

Comment: i think this is similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169062/mongodb-how-to-remove-value-from-array-if-exist-otherwise-add

Answer (score 8):

If you are updating the document, you can use the pipeline within the *update*. But this feature is available with MongoDB version 4.2 or later.

```
db.collection.update(
  { },
  [
     { 
          $set: { 
              arr: { 
                  $cond: [ { $in: [ element, "$arr" ] }, 
                           { $setDifference: [ "$arr", [ element ] ] }, 
                           { $concatArrays: [ "$arr", [ element ] ] } 
                  ] 
              }
          }
     }
  ]
)
```

**NOTE:** Assuming the variable `element` is a *string* value.

If you are just querying you can use the following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     { 
          $addFields: { 
              arr: { 
                  $cond: [ { $in: [ element, "$arr" ] }, 
                           { $setDifference: [ "$arr", [ element ] ] }, 
                           { $concatArrays: [ "$arr", [ element ] ] } 
                  ] 
              }
          }
     }
] )
```

But, if you are using MongoDB version earlier than 4.2, then you can use the aggregate output from above to update the document:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  // aggregation pipeine from above ...
] ).forEach( doc => db.collection.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { arr: doc.arr } } ) )
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I'll be sure to try this out soon. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! One small caveat, this will fail if `$arr` does not exist. A more robust solution involves nesting two `$cond`s, for example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rFFrkytAM1D

Comment: Code snippets are not be assumed as a programming solution as it is, to be used in an application. In an application there will be validations, error handling and scenarios for solving a business rule. This is meant to be a way of solving a code, more of understanding a technique or using an API. @djanowski Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Its maybe not the best solution, but a easy one. You can add your element to the array with `$addToSet` and check with `nModified` if you modified the array. `0` means it already exist, and `1` mean you added new Element to it.

So you use mongoose as you said then you have a Model lets say `Post`. I dont know witch backend langauge you use, but i will show it with node.js here:

```
let result = await Post.updateOne({ _id: "someId" }, { 
   $addToSet: {
      arr: element
   }
})

if(result.nModified === 0){
   //0 means, no modifikation, that means its already liked
   await Post.updateOne({ _id: "someId" }, {
      $pull: {
         arr: element
      }
   })
}
response.send("Done");
```

Comment: That was my previous implementation and what I wanted to avoid. Thank you none the less.